# How to toggle through states?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I search for a short and readable way to toggle through states.

E.g. gender states:  m -> f -> n

Right now I use either

```
if (this.gender === "m") this.gender = "f";
    else if (this.gender === "f") this.gender = "n";
    else this.gender = "m";
```

or

```
this.gender = this.gender === "m" ? "f" : this.gender === "f" ? "n" : "m";
```

Both are horrible. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a mapping table:

```
const mapping = {
    'm': 'f',
    'f': 'n',
    'n': 'm',
}
```

and use it as such:

```
this.gender = mapping[this.gender];
```

// Edit
My another solution was already provided by @VRoxa in the meantime.

Comment: Holy cow, that is clever!

Answer (score 1):

Well, another shorter but also cryptic way of doing this would be iterating through an ordered array.

```
const genders = [ 'm', 'f', 'n' ];
let index = 0;

const toggle = () =>
  genders[(++index) % 3];
```

Even you could define handlers for different iterations

```
const genders = [ 'm', 'f', 'n' ];

const toggleHandler = () => {
  let index = 0;
  return () => genders[(++index) % 3];
}

const toggle = toggleHandler();

// Decice whether you want to increment
// then return or vice-versa
console.log(toggle()); // f
console.log(toggle()); // n
console.log(toggle()); // m
console.log(toggle()); // f
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I also had this solution, but it is hardly as readable as the other two.

Comment: Then use an `enum`, since you are using Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really fun question actually, here's some methods that come to mind:

Using a String and offsetting:

```
var genderpath = "mfn";

gender = genderpath[(genderpath.indexOf(gender)+1)%genderpath.length];
```

Using an object:

```
var genders = {'m': 'f', 'f': 'n', 'n': 'm'};

gender = genders[gender];
```

Using a combination of solutions(probably the best):

```
var genderpath = "mfnm";

gender = genderpath[genderpath.indexOf(gender)+1];
```

Comment: That last one is beautiful! Though Benjamins answer is probably more readable.